# Writing an xml to assets folder from asmx web service

Tags: android, web-services

i have an asmx web service that interacts with database to retreive data for my android application.
is there a way, i can write all the data in an xml file to the assets folder of my android application from the web service?

Comment: yes, to do this get the file from assets using Context and then write content on it.

Comment: The files in the assets folder are read-only.